# CSS border-image keyframe animation works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a `div` with a gradient `border-image` and an `animation` property which changes the gradient's `deg` (degrees) in keyframes.

This works perfectly in Firefox but not in Chrome. In fact, in Chrome, the element doesn't have a border at all. It's like the browser simply gives up when it sees the element has an `animation` property.

Here's a Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0nymc9ej/2/

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

div {
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #ff0000, #00ff00, #0000ff) 1 / 5px;
  animation: move 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
    0%   { border-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #ff0000, #00ff00, #0000ff) 1 / 5px; }
  25%  { border-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff0000, #00ff00, #0000ff) 1 / 5px; }
  50%  { border-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #ff0000, #00ff00, #0000ff) 1 / 5px; }
  75%  { border-image: linear-gradient(270deg, #ff0000, #00ff00, #0000ff) 1 / 5px; }
  100% { border-image: linear-gradient(360deg, #ff0000, #00ff00, #0000ff) 1 / 5px; }
}
```

```html
<div>This has a nice moving border in Firefox but not in Chrome</div>
```

1. Why does this not work in Chrome but does in Firefox?
2. Is there any way to get this working in Chrome without using pseudo-elements, JavaScript, or other hacky ways?
3. Is there a way to make the gradient changes "fade" smoothly into each other (without simply adding more keyframes) as the animation looks really jerky right now?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea using mask:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.box {
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position:relative;
  padding:5px; /* this will control the border width */
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box div{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  inset:0; /* shorthand of top right bottom left */
  padding: inherit;
  /* make the gradient visible only inside the padding area */
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box,
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) padding-box;
  -webkit-mask-composite:destination-out;
  mask-composite:exclude;
  /**/
}
/* a rotating gradient layer */
.box div::before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  inset:-50%;
  background:linear-gradient(#ff0000, #00ff00, #0000ff);
  animation: move 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
  100% { transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 <div></div>
This has a nice moving border</div>
```

In the near future you can do it using CSS variable like below (works only on Chrome and edge for now)

```css
@property --a{
  syntax: '<angle>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0deg;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

div {
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid;
  --a:0deg; /* fallback for FF to see the border */
  border-image: linear-gradient(var(--a), #ff0000, #00ff00, #0000ff) 1 / 5px;
  animation: move 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
   100%{--a:360deg}
}
```

```html
<div>This has a nice moving border</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying - I should have said I would like to avoid using pseudo-elements. Also I wondered why Chrome doesn't support this but Firefox does. I'll edit my original question.

Comment: @WackGet pseudo element is not mandatory here, if you don't want to use it add another html element inside the div. You cannot animate gradient so you cannot achieve what you want using border-image only (unless you use future method, see the updates). Until then you need to do it differently

Comment: My snippet does animate in Firefox but not in Chrome. Maybe Firefox supports animating gradients? Your snippet isn't animating for me in Firefox.

Comment: @WackGet your snippet is not animating, you are having a discrete animation . My first snippet does animate on Firefox and chrome and my second snippet only Chrome because I am using a new feature not yet supported on Firefox

Comment: Ah I see, yes, thanks. So why does discrete animation work on Firefox but not Chrome?